# reactJS - Adding an event handler to an element which might, or might not exist at this time

Tags: events, event-bubbling

I am not allowed to answer questions yet, but I feel that since this issue has taken me some days to resolve, I should post the solution the only way I can - as a question.

If you have a better solution then please include that in your reply.

Until an element is rendered it is not in the DOM so if you add an event listener to the element in your code you will get an error (element value null).

But you can add a listener to the root element, which is always there.  WHen the event is triggered you can then retrieve the className and ID of the element involved in your event-handler.

Code:

```
     var rootElement = document.getElementById('root'); 
     console.log(rootElement);
     rootElement.addEventListener('click', rootElementClicked);

    console.log('event listener added to root element');

    function rootElementClicked(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      const { name, value } = event.target;

      console.log("Root element clicked with [" + event.target.className, event.target.id);
    }
```

/code
So, the event-listener is app-wide, so a click anywhere will call the event-handler function.  Then in the code for that function, the element class and ID will tell you what was clicked.

Note the event.preventDefault(); line - it prevents a refresh of the web page, otherwise the target class & ID are returned as "undefined"

Comment: What does this have to do with React?

Comment: It is not really React related. In React you would attach your clickEvent with onClick={myFunction} and then in the render check if the element should be rendered like: myVariable && <MyComponent />

Answer (score 1):

In React you shouldn't need to addEventListener manually since you can use onClick. However if you would like to manually attach click handler on an HTML element in React you can use React Ref. If you pass a ref object to React with `<div ref={myRef} />` React will set its `.current` property to the corresponding DOM node whenever that node changes.

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-useref-xfvlb

```
const App = () => {
  const elementRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    elementRef.current.addEventListener('click', handleOnClick);
  },[elementRef])

  const handleOnClick = () => {
    alert("click")
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div ref={elementRef}>
       click on me
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes, I discovered this eventually :-)  The lack of a decent reactJS manual and the inability of the reactJS team to keep their solutions up to date (eg: there are countless solutionson the reactJS website using the deprecated class approach which have not yet been updated to utilise hooks).  This makes it difficult to avoid going down numerous rabbit holes to find a workable solution.  The 'solution' to attach an event handler to the root Div being one of them :-(

Comment: This work so well thanks

Comment: What if the element that has the ref is conditionally rendered? How can you add and event listener then?